# Values Not Updated in Database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a product attribute table, in that, I have 2 text fields. So when I enter the values in all text field box. And when I press the update button. the first input row is updated successfully but the others not. Here is the picture of the blade file:

[image]

Here is my code
**Blade.php**

```
<form name="editAttributeForm" id="editAttributeForm" method="post" action="{{url('admin/edit-attributes/'.$productdata['id'])}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3 class="card-title">Added Product Attributes</h3>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-header -->
                <div class="card-body">
                    <table id="products" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Size</th>
                                <th>SKU</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th>Stock</th>
                                <th>Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach ($productdata['attributes'] as $attribute)
                            <!-- getting the attribute fields ids  -->
                            <input style="display: none;" type="text" name="attrId[]" value="{{$attribute['id']}}">
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$attribute['id']}}</td>
                                <td>{{$attribute['size']}}</td>
                                <td>{{$attribute['sku']}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="number" name="price[]" value="{{$attribute['price']}}" required="">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="number" name="stock[]" value="{{$attribute['stock']}}" required="">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @if($attribute['status']==1)
                                    <a class="updateAttributeStatus" id="attribute-{{$attribute['id']}}" attribute_id="{{$attribute['id']}}" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fas fa-toggle-on" aria-hidden='true' status="Active"></i></a>
                                    @else
                                    <a class="updateAttributeStatus" id="attribute-{{$attribute['id']}}" attribute_id="{{$attribute['id']}}" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fas fa-toggle-off" aria-hidden='true' status="Inactive"></i></a>
                                    @endif
                                    &nbsp;
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="confirmDelete" record="attribute" recordid="{{$attribute['id']}}" title="Delete Product"><i class="far fa-trash-alt text-danger"></i></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-body -->
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Update Attributes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.card -->
        </form>
```

**ProductsController.php**

```
public function editAttributes(Request $request, $id)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $data = $request->all();
        // echo "<pre>";
        // print_r($data);
        // die;

        foreach ($data['attrId'] as $key => $attr) {
            if (!empty($attr)) {
                ProductsAttribute::where(['id' => $data['attrId'][$key]])->update(['price' => $data['price'][$key], 'stock' => $data['stock'][$key]]);
            }

            $success_message = "Product attributes has been updated successfully!";
            session::flash("attSuccess_message", $success_message);
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have a loop and you are breaking out of it and the method itself in the first iteration with the `return` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your `ProductsController.php` as following, it might work.

```
public function editAttributes(Request $request, $id)
    {
        if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
            $data = $request->all();

            foreach ($data['attrId'] as $key => $attr) {
                if (!empty($attr)) {
                    ProductsAttribute::where(['id' => $data['attrId'][$key]])
                        ->update(['price' => $data['price'][$key], 'stock' => $data['stock'][$key]]);
                }
            }

            // You can check all attributes, updated or not if you wish
            
            $success_message = "Product attributes has been updated successfully!";
            session::flash("attSuccess_message", $success_message);
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
```

Comment: "_it might work_" Or it might not? What was the problem? What did you change?

Comment: As he told, 1st row is working that means his code is working, but there was a little issue with the return statement  in loop, please check my code block @brombeer